# RTL bootstrap Popover arrow customization using css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on direction RTL using bootstrap. I am facing issue on popover if the direction was LTR. The popover arrow should be in left else it should be in right.

Example: right now my direction is LTR <

RTL >

Here is my CSS:

```
.popover.right > .arrow {
 top: 50%;
 left: -11px;
 margin-top: -11px;
 border-left-width: 0;
 border-right-color: #999999;
 border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 }
.popover.right > .arrow:after {
 content: " ";
 left: 1px;
 bottom: -10px;
 border-left-width: 0;
 border-right-color: #ffffff;
 }
.popover > .arrow:after {
border-width: 10px;
content: "";
}
.popover > .arrow, .popover > .arrow:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
}
```

So I have tried using

```
   html[dir="rtl"] .popover.left >.arrow{
   top: 50%;
   right: -11px;
   margin-top: -11px;
   border-left-width: 0;
   border-left-color: #999999;
   border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
```

I am using the CSS like

```
<div class="popover"></div>
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Plz add the hole HTML tag to check out.
Is your LTR CSS works correct? I mean when you remove the `DIR='rtl'` it works correctly or not?

therefore I think that may cause from your HTML Coding.